# How to optionally load expensive viewmodels for partial views?

Tags: devexpress, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

DevExpress's PageControl loads the content for the selected tab page on demand:

```
@Model IndexViewModel

@Html.DevExpress().PageControl(settings =>
{
    settings.TabPages.Add("Dashboard").SetContent(() =>
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_Dashboard", ???);
    });
    settings.TabPages.Add("Review photos (3)").SetContent(() =>
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_ReviewPhotos", ???);
    });
    ...
}
```

However this makes it difficult to pass the view models into each partial view as they each have their own requirements.

Options:

1) **All views & partials share the same view model**, simply pass Model through - unfortunately means the controller must load all content for all pages on every request which is too inefficient

2) **Have separate view models nested, pass Model.[Child]ViewModel through** - same inefficiencies as (1)

3) **Have loading functions on main view's model** eg.:

```
settings.TabPages.Add("Dashboard").SetContent(() =>
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Dashboard", Model.CreateDashboardViewModel());
});

settings.TabPages.Add("Review photos (3)").SetContent(() =>
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_ReviewPhotos", Model.CreateReviewPhotosViewModel());
});

...

public class IndexViewModel
{
    public Func<DashboardPhotosViewModel> CreateDashboardPhotosViewModel { get; set; }
    public Func<ReviewPhotosViewModel> CreateReviewPhotosViewModel { get; set; }
}

...

var viewModel = new IndexViewModel 
{
    CreateDashboardPhotosViewModel = () => 
    {
        //Load dashboard specific elements
    }
    ...
}
```

4) **Don't render partials directly** - do through Html.RenderAction("..") instead allowing viewmodels to be created within the action method.  (This is a possibility but may cause other issues, so I'm interested to hear alternatives)

I like (3) but it seems like an anti pattern to put functions on a view model.

I also require the ability to create these child view models individually for AJAX callbacks etc.

Is there a best practice way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, we went with option (4) - call the Action on the controller, which can create its own viewmodel.